TAURI V2: Trouble with the file system’s mkdir
So I’m trying to make a directory in TypeScript, but for some reason, it’s giving me an error saying “forbidden path: images”.  I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong here, and I’ve been having a ton of trouble figuring it out.  Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong here?
TypeScript:
const imagesDir = `images`;
const deckDir = deckName;
const filePath = `${imagesDir}/${fileName}`;

// Check and create directory if not exists
const dirExists = await fs.exists(imagesDir);
if (!dirExists) {
      await fs.mkdir(imagesDir, { baseDir: fs.BaseDirectory.AppData });
}

migrated.json permissions:
{
  "identifier": "migrated",
  "description": "permissions that were migrated from v1",
  "local": true,
  "windows": [
    "main"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "core:default",
    "shell:allow-open",
    "fs:default",
    "fs:allow-open",
    "fs:allow-write",
    "fs:allow-read",
    "fs:allow-rename",
    "fs:allow-mkdir",
    "fs:allow-remove",
    "fs:allow-write-text-file",
    "fs:scope-download-recursive",
    "fs:scope-resource-recursive",
    {
      "identifier": "fs:scope",
      "allow": [{ "path": "$APPDATA" }, {"path": "$APPDATA/*" }]
    },
    "shell:default",
    "dialog:default"
  ]
}

Rust:
tauri::Builder::default()
    .setup(|app| {
        let path = app.path().app_data_dir().expect("This should never be None");
        let path = path.join("images/");

        create_dir_all(&path)?;

        Ok(())
    })
    .plugin(tauri_plugin_dialog::init())
    .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
    .plugin(tauri_plugin_fs::init())
    .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
        /*REDACTED*/
    ])
    .on_window_event(|window, event| {
        if let WindowEvent::CloseRequested { .. } = event {
            // Perform the save action here
            if let Err(e) = save_to_disk() {
                eprintln!("Failed to save data to disk: {}", e);
            }
        }
    })
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("error while running tauri application");

In my JSON file, I had the second path as “$APPDATA/**”, which also did not seem to work, and in my main.rs, I had “/.images” as my path, but that did not work either, idk how important that is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
I tried changing the permissions, paths, and even base directory, expecting for the app to make a copy of the file and save it, but for some reason, it keeps giving me the error, “forbidden path: images”.  I explained everything I tried in the description.
